# IIS 7.0 - URL Rewriting Root Folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config

I have done a bunch of sites using URL Rewrite actions in the `web.config` with much success.

Today I am trying to do the following rewrite rule:

Example url: domainname.com/ANYTHINGHERE/PRODUCTID

I basically want to take the product ID and pass it to a page (i.e. product.aspx?id=PRODUCTID

```
<rule name="Rewrite Product Details Page" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="/product-view.aspx?id={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />                    
</rule>
```

I've done this in the past just fine but it had to have a static root folder, for instance: domanname.com/products/ANYTHINGHERE/ID

**EDIT:** (forgot to describe my issue),

When I try to load my page - domain.com/categoryname/PRODUCTID

The product page is called by the ID is not passed in.

Any ideas? I searched and could not find anything.

-Joe

Comment: You did not describe the problem itself. Does it rewrite to a wrong url or does an exception occur or what else?

Comment: Thank you Linus, You are correct. I updated the post with the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the index is not zero-based. Try

```
<rule name="Rewrite Product Details Page" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/product-view.aspx?id={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />                    
</rule>
```

Here is a good tutorial: [Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

Comment: That actually worked. I'm not sure I understand why but it did! Now I just have to setup static maps for set directories such as CSS and IMAGES etc.. Thanks for your help!